# SQl sort data by multiple columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, sorting

I need to sort the following table from the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Likelihood WITH (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN Diagnosis ON Diagnosis.DiagnosisID = Likelihood.DiagnosisID
WHERE Likelihood.SessionID = (6768) 
ORDER BY Likelihood.Percentage DESC
```

```
    **Percentage   Diagnosis   Level**
    100            F43.10      HIGH
    83.333336      F84.5       HIGH
    75             F40.9       HIGH
    66.666664      F90.0       MEDIUM
    50             F51.09      MEDIUM
```

First sort by `Likelihood.Percentage` in descending.

Then when Level = 'HIGH' then sort by Diagnosis ascending. Diagnosis column is a string.

When Level = 'MEDIUM' then sort by Diagnosis ascending

The resulting table should be:

```
**Percentage   Diagnosis   Level**
100            F43.10      HIGH
75             F40.9       HIGH
83.333336      F84.5       HIGH
50             F51.09      MEDIUM
66.666664      F90.0       MEDIUM
```

I tried this query, but did not get the results:

```
SELECT *
FROM Likelihood WITH (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN Diagnosis ON Diagnosis.DiagnosisID = Likelihood.DiagnosisID
WHERE Likelihood.SessionID = (6768) 
ORDER BY 
    case when Level='HIGH' and Percentage > 70 then Diagnosis.Diagnosis end
    , case when Level='Medium' and Percentage between 50 and 69 then Diagnosis.Diagnosis end
    , Likelihood.Percentage DESC
```

Comment: Unrelated comment: It's REALLY bad practice to just throw in "WITH (NOLOCK)" like that. Never use that unless you absolutely, positively HAVE to and have no other recourse. It's just a really bad habit to get into.

Comment: Your statement of how you want to sort makes no sense to me. You say FIRST sort by percentage... well, each percentage is unique so there's no way a secondary sort criteria will ever come into play. And your example 'results' shows that you're FIRST sorting by 'Level" (High = 1st, Medium = 2nd, presumably anything else = 3rd). So what you're really saying is ORDER BY Level ASC, Diagnosis DESC. If you don't mean that, then your question needs to be updated, because I find your statement of the problem to be ambiguous at best.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly,  you simply need to specify a few order by conditions. First is Percentage, then Level (HIGH should be before the MEDIUM because of alphabetic sorting), and then by Diagnosis.
So,

```
order by 
    Percentage DESC,
    Level ASC, 
    Diagnosis ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

it is an example for multi column sort :

```
SELECT city,first_name,last_name
 FROM
sales.customers
ORDER BY
city DESC,
first_name ASC;
```

for more guide check below link

https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-order-by/